# $T$ automorphism of $G$. Construct the semidirect product $\{G,T\}=\{x^ig\}$. Why must $o(x)=o(T)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, automorphism-group

I apologize if the title is unclear, but I've just found this while reading Herstein's *Topics in Algebra* (p. 69) and I am not familiar with semidirect products. My query is this.

Herstein constructs a new group from $G$ by using an automorphism $T$ of $G$. If $T$ has order $r$, he adds the formal symbol $x$ with the following rules: $x^r=e \in G$; $x^{-1}gx=gT$ (his notation to indicate the image of $g$ through $T$). It follows that the set $\{x^ig \mid i \in \Bbb Z_r; g \in G\}$ has the structure of a group.

But consider the trivial case $T=I$, the identity automorphism. It seems to me that there is no restriction on the order of $x$ here. For example, we can create a group with the above-mentioned rules except $x^2=e, x \not = e$. If $G$ is finite, $\{ G, T\}$ will have twice as many elements as $G$. In general, it seems that we can let $o(x)$ be any multiple of $o(T)$. Why does Herstein not bother with this case?

Comment: Yes, you are right, but so what? I don't really understand what you are asking.

Comment: Well, wouldn't this make the construction of a larger group from $G$ much easier? I mean, according to Herstein, if one is to create a group that's, say, 3 times as large as $G$, one would have to find an automorphism $T$ of order 3. This is definitely more difficult than simply choosing $T=I$ and letting $o(x)=3$, etc., as I have sketched. Of course the different choices of $T$ give rise to very different $\{G,T\}$'s, and maybe $\{G,I\}$ is not particularly interesting? But I was wondering why Herstein wouldn't show the reader this possibility.

Comment: You certainly need the order of $T$ to divide whatever order you give to $x$ for there to be no collapse due to the identities; but if the order of $T$ is a proper divisor of $x$, then you have that $x^r$ is not trivial but acts trivially; basically, you end up getting direct products instead of getting semidirect products. In your example, what you construct is just $G\times C_2$, since $x^{-1}gx = gI = g$ for all $g$. So you aren’t really constructing semi-direct products, you are constructing direct products.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I don't even know what a direct product is, and I don't know why semidirect or direct products are useful. But thank you, I think I will soon read about them.